# Startup-Log "No Transaction manager found"

Tags: transactions, jetty

When I start jetty, following line appears in Log:

```
:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found
- if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
```

- What does it means?
- How do I know that my webapp requires a transaction manager?
- Which features serves such transaction manager or what am I missing if I do not have one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically if you need one, you know you need one.

Transaction managers like Atomikos or JOTM are what are being referred to here.  Used for distributed transactions leveraging the JTA api:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API

So in jetty's case it is an informational message that no such api has been bound via jndi on startup when using the jetty-plus configuration.  jetty-plus in of itself is a module for integrating to resources that are outside of the strict servlet-api sense but are still often useful for people.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this warn message and have config transaction manager in spring config-file.

But everything is normal,so,i think you can ignore this message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294648/there-are-two-questions-when-i-start-jetty