# How to configure TransactionManager programmatically

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I'm having an application here based on Spring MVC. My workmate (btw he's not here) configured it programmatically and everything seems to work, except for the TransactionManager. I have never configured a Spring web application like this and I have no clue what to do and also can not find any documentation about how to configure a webapplication like this.

I'll just show you the 'AppInitializer' and the 'EntityManagerConfig'.

AppInitializer:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context;
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcherServletRegistration;
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilterRegistration, compressionFilterRegistration;
    Set<SessionTrackingMode> sessionTrackingModes = new HashSet<SessionTrackingMode>();

    sessionTrackingModes.add(SessionTrackingMode.SSL);

    context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setServletContext(servletContext);
    context.scan("de.devbliss.doc");

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    servletContext.addListener(new Log4jConfigListener());

    dispatcherServletRegistration = servletContext.addServlet("main", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcherServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcherServletRegistration.addMapping("/*");

    encodingFilterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
    encodingFilterRegistration.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    encodingFilterRegistration.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    encodingFilterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    compressionFilterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("compressionFilter", GzipFilter.class);
    compressionFilterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    compressionFilterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain",
            DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
    compressionFilterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(sessionTrackingModes);
}
}
```

EntityManagerConfig:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/db.properties")
public class EntityManagerConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(Environment env) {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

    ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("url", "localhost"));
    ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("user", "blissdoc"));
    ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("password", "s3cret"));

    return ds;
}

@Bean
@Inject
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
        SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager tm = new HibernateTransactionManager(
            sessionFactory);
    return tm;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
@Inject
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager(
        DataSource dataSource, AbstractEnvironment env) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    HibernateJpaDialect jpaDialect = new HibernateJpaDialect();
    org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<?> source;
    Iterator<org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<?>> sources;

    // jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);

    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

    sources = env.getPropertySources().iterator();
    while (sources.hasNext()) {
        source = sources.next();
        if (source.getSource() instanceof Map) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> property : ((Map<String, String>) source
                    .getSource()).entrySet()) {
                jpaProperties.put(property.getKey(), property.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    em.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("blissdoc-unit");
    em.setPackagesToScan("de.devbliss.doc.model");
    em.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect);
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);

    return em;
}

// @Bean
// @Inject
// public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(
// EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
// JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager(
// entityManagerFactory);
// return tm;
// }

@Bean
@Inject
public JpaRepositoryFactory jpaRepositoryFactory(
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaRepositoryFactory factory = new JpaRepositoryFactory(
            entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
@Inject
public UserRepository userRepository(
        JpaRepositoryFactory jpaRepositoryFactory) {
    return jpaRepositoryFactory.getRepository(UserRepository.class);
}

@Bean
@Inject
public ProjectRepository projectRepository(
        JpaRepositoryFactory jpaRepositoryFactory) {
    return jpaRepositoryFactory.getRepository(ProjectRepository.class);
}
}
```

--- Update
PersistenceJPAConfig (former EntityManagerConfig):

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:/db.properties")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

@Inject
private Environment env;

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "de.devbliss.doc" });
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        {
            // JPA properties
        }
    };
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("url", "localhost"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("user", "blissdoc"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("password", "s3cret"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean()
            .getObject());

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
}
```

Comment: Here's the link to TransactionManager, http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html

Comment: This link only describes xml-configured TransactionManager but I'll have to stick with programmatic configuration.

Comment: This section only describes programmatic transaction management. Not programmatic configuration of a TransactionManager. Also this piece of documentation is for Spring 2.0. As far as I know, this version didn't yet know programmatic configuration at all.

Comment: My bad for giving the incorrect link. Yes, the versions 3.x.x started providing the annotation and programmatic way of configuring the same. You can find the links of your specific version at, http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/. I'm using 3.0.7 and the section 10.5.6 of http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/transaction.html has your solution.

Comment: as I remember, these annotation-based configuration (it is not really "programmatic") is just another way (apart from XML) to present the configuration to Spring.  The idea should be the same isn't it?  How is the configuration "not working"?

Comment: For know it seems like it the configuration itself does work but Jetty still says "No transaction manager configured". Updated configuration in top post. And why shouldn't this be a programmatic configuration?

Comment: You are probably seeing this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339758/startup-log-no-transaction-manager-found, it is just an information message that no JTA compliant transaction manager is registered with Jetty, not specific to your web application

Answer (score 7):

`@Configuration`-specific counterparts of custom XML elements such as `<tx:annotation-driven>` are `@Enable...` annotations.

In order to enable support for `@Transactional` you need to annotate your `@Configuration` class with `@EnableTransactionManagement`:

```
@Configuration 
@PropertySource("classpath:/db.properties") 
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class EntityManagerConfig { ... }
```

**See also:**

- [`@EnableTransactionManagement`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html)
- [Spring 3.1 M2: Configuration Enhancements](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/06/10/spring-3-1-m2-configuration-enhancements/)

Comment: Thanks, the EnableTransactionManagement annotation is added but Jetty still claims there is no transaction manager configured. Also see my updated question with the new configuration.

Comment: @entek: As far as I remember, this message from Jetty has nothing to do with Spring transaction management, you can ignore it.

Comment: Ok, let's assume this message is from something else and does not matter. So I create a new User (from my UserModel) and call `userRepository.save(user)`. No error is thrown but nothing is written to the database. If I call `userRepository.flush()`, I get the following message: `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`

Comment: I could post the UserController and UserRepository in my original post if you think it might help you.

Comment: Not really.. The problem was the strange behavior of the TransactionManager. But we just decided to live with it and leave it that way.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to extend from `TransactionManagementConfigurer`?

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:/db.properties")
public class EntityManagerConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    ...

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return transactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        transactionManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    ...
}
```

And seems like you are using Spring Data JPA, so I recommend you to use also `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.your.repositories.package")` to automatically configure your Spring Data Repositories.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. Where do `entityManagerFactory()` and `dataSource` come from? I don't see them defined in this snippet.